# Understanding the Occupancy under PIX 2303.30

Tags: graphics, directx, directx-11, directx-12

I am profiling my renderer to do some optimization.
To help me I use PIX 2303.30 and I successfully get captures. I have theses questions about the occupancy:

1. What is really the occupancy, why does it ranges from 0 to 10?
2. It looks like the VS and PS shader occupancies are added together. Why?
3. Why does it stops in the middle on a timelapse?(See pink line)
   [image]

Thanks for helping!